# How to use Observable correctly in a list?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using Angular 2.

When I have only one element, I can use `nativeElement` first and then use `Observable`.

```
<div #aaa></div>

@ViewChild('aaa') private aaa: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(Observable.fromEvent(this.aaa.nativeElement), 'mouseenter');
}
```

But now I have a list, I cannot use same way to do it:

```
<a *ngFor="#user of users" #aaa (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event, user)">
  {{user}}
</a>

@ViewChild('aaa') private aaa: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(Observable.fromEvent(this.aaa.nativeElement), 'mouseenter');
}
```

It will show the error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

When the mouses move into each element, I want it does different things using Observable. How can I correctly use Observable in this case?

Comment: @ViewChildren('aaa') hrefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

Comment: and in ngAfterViewInit: this.hrefs.toArray().forEach((child) => console.log(Observable.fromEvent(child.nativeElement, 'mouseenter')));

Comment: @yurzui thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of how to do what you're trying to do here, I would suggest:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <a *ngFor="#user of users" (mouseenter)="mouseEnters$.next({event: $event, user: user})">
    {{user}}
  </a>
  `
})
class YourComponent { 
   mouseEnters$: Subject<data:{event: MouseEvent, user: any}> = BehaviorSubject.create();

   ngAfterViewInit(){ //you don't actually need to wait for afterViewInit anymore
       this.mouseEnters$.subscribe((data:{event:MouseEvent, user: any}) => /* do whatever */)
   }
}
```

In terms of why you're getting the exception you're getting - you can't put a template variable on an element with `ngFor` on it (which makes sense when you realize that the element is repeated...), and consequently the `@ViewChild` is null.

Comment: could you please explain why we cant add local variable with the *ngFor ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Because that element is going to be repeated n times (where n is the size of your list of users). Which of those elements would `aaa` be?

Comment: so in that case what would be the local variable ? index of *ngFor or something else ?

Comment: There is no local variable, in the sense that (I think) you're thinking about it. This would amount to creating them dynamically, [which is explicitly not supported](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554). The case I mentioned above was hypothetical - you can't actually do that.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you though - what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @drewmoore thanks!! The traditional way I can get user value `(mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event, user)"`. But now the user I got in the `this.mouseEnters$.subscribe((event, user) => console.log(user));` is `undefined`. Maybe some place wrong?

Comment: @HongboMiao sorry, I hadn't updated the syntax in the subscription to reflect a change I made to the subject. Please see edit.

Comment: @drewmoore `(event:MouseEvent, user: any) =>` still can run, but `user` is undefined, but now if change to `{event:MouseEvent, user: any} =>` even cannot run..

Comment: @HongboMiao gah, sorry again - you just need to wrap the the object literal in `( )`

Comment: @drewmoore Right now, in `this.mouseEnters$.subscribe((event: MouseEvent, user: any) =>`, I got `event` value, but `user` is undefined. I think something is still wrong. However, `event.user` actually is `user` value now.

Comment: @drewmoore Oh I got where the error is. I will let you know soon!

Comment: @drewmoore Only some parts should change a little bit. The correct one should be `mouseEnters$: Subject<{data: { event: MouseEvent, user: any }}> = BehaviorSubject.create();` and `this.mouseEnters$.subscribe((data: { event: MouseEvent, user: any }) => {`, then inside use like `data.user` and `data.event`. Then everything works perfect!

Comment: @HongboMiao right you are! good debugging! that'll teach me to post from my phone without testing in an IDE :-P Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to do later with `user` or `event`, `Observable` and `ViewChild` seems to be overkill, just do:

```
<a *ngFor="#user of users" #aaa (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event, user)">
  {{user}}
</a>

mouseEnter(event, user) {
  console.log(event, user);
  //do smth. i.e. this.eventEmitter.emit(user);
}
```

Comment: Observables only seem like overkill until you understand them. Once you do, you'll regard them as a primitive type - which they effectively are in ng2 apps.

Comment: ^^ I only say that because it wasn't long ago that I didn't fully understand them and felt the same way. Now that I do, I like angular2 **a lot** more.

Comment: well, my answer refers this specific question, not observables in general. It seems that for this particular case there is no need to use observable.

Comment: If OP's use case is actually as simple as what they posted here, then you're right. I think it's safe to assume that they were just posting an over-simplified SSCCE though.